# Как передать данные между sockets?

Tags: php, сокет, websocket

Открыто 2 сокета на сервере по адресу 1.1.1.0 и портам :3000 и :4000. Их обрабатывают два скрипта PHP.
Команду "takebeer" от клинта1 на порту (:3000) нужно передать клинту2 на порту (:4000). Как это реализовать?

Comment: А тег с++ вы тут зачем написали ? Какое отношение с++ имеет к скриптам на php ?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тегам, Вы путаете механизмы Sockets и WebSockets, которые являются совершенно разными технологиями. Впрочем, для обоих случаев есть неплохо расписанные мануалы по использованию:

Для Sockets: 
http://www.funphp.com/2010/12/01/create-a-socket-server-in-php-and-run-as-a-service/

Для WebSockets:
http://petukhovsky.com/simple-web-socket-on-php-from-very-start/